# MongoDB: remove skill from user document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I have an issue. I have a MongoDB `user` document and this document has a property skills, which is an array filled with objects.

What I want to do now is the following. The client sends a request to delete one of these skills. So I send the skill ID and then I want to remove the skill from the user. How could I do this?

**What I currently have: every item in the `skills` property array has a `skill` property which is an `objectID`. When this objectID matches the objectId that the client sent, then we want to remove this skill from the user**

```
const removeSkill = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { userId, params: { skillId } } = req;

    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: userId }, {
      $pull: { "skills.skill": skillId }
    }, {
      new: true
    });

    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'succesfully removed skill',
      user
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return sendErr(res, err);
  }
};
```

**What the user mongodb document looks like**

[image]

**The error I get**

```
:no_entry: Error:
MongoError: Cannot use the part (skill) of (skills.skill) to traverse the element ({skills: [ { _id: ObjectId('5c8729be12e1cc05c04ea182'), name: "javascript", skill: ObjectId('5c8729be
12e1cc05c04ea181'), points: 22 }, { _id: ObjectId('5c8729dc12e1cc05c04ea184'), name: "node.js", skill: ObjectId('5c8729dc12e1cc05c04ea183'), points: 14 }, { _id: ObjectId('5c872a6c12e1c
c05c04ea186'), name: "css", skill: ObjectId('5c872a6c12e
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused by what you are exactly asking for, your solution is already working, no?

Comment: Hey muhand, it's not working unfortunately. But I noticed I forgot to add the error it throws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't be using 2 Object ID in one object. The beauty of MongoDB is auto generated ObjectID. For your question (using **skill** ObjectID)

```
 const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
     { _id: userId }, 
     { $pull: { "skills": { skill: skillId }}}, 
     { new: true}
    );
```

I believe u are receiving **ObjectID** from your params. If so,Something like this should help.